# jquery validation for specific button onclick

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i am using jquery client side validation in asp.net.

the problem i am facing now is that whenever i click any button in a page it causes validation rather than for specific button alone.

how to resolve this .?

thank you

Comment: Can you please clarify. What does 'whenever i click any button in a page it causes validation rather than for specific button alone' mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have two buttons SubmitButton and CancelButton and you do not want to CancelButton to fire validation plugin, just give **CssClass="cancel"** for CancelButton

```
    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" 
            Text="Return to List" 
            CssClass="cancel" />
```

Comment: Thank you naveen ..it works..if you can explain the exact reason for this?

Comment: @SAK: Jörn Zaefferer designed the plugin like that. I dont see any documentation for that though

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `event.preventDefault()`.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

```
$("button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do stuff here
});
```